# How exec() works - PHP and Wordpress

Tags: php, shell, exec

I am working with `wordpress` and I have a list of articles in `csv`, my function in php is already working it is inside the `theme_options.php` file along with other various functions of the wordpress theme, but I would like to only run the function that registers the csv this in the background.

I would like to understand how I do this run my function in the background

I know this is an extremely generic question, but I would like to understand how the exec works and at what time I should call it in my function

```
function example() {

    if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {       

        $lines = file(''.get_template_directory_uri() . '/list.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_TEXT);

        foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line){ 

                //some code to save csv line content            
        }
    }
} 
add_action( 'init', 'example' );
```

**EDIT**

would that be correct?

`csv_test.php` code:

```
            $lines = file(''.get_template_directory_uri() . '/list.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_TEXT);

            foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line){ 

                    //some code to save csv line content            
            }
```

`theme_options.php` code:

```
     function example() { 
 if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {              
            exec("php csv_test.php > /dev/null &");
        } 
}
        add_action( 'init', 'example' );
```

Comment: what you want to do? save a file in the hd?

Comment: @Vidal I edited my question please see

Answer (score 0):

With exec you can execute an external program. http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

To run on the background you can create a cron job and run a wget url.